# Microservice architecture implementation of CRM HRM and Domain design problems

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, crm, erp, microservices

We are building a enterprise platform that consists of CRM, HRM, SALE, PROPERTY etc.
We are working on the microservice architecture.

**The real question is:**
CRM and HRM will be deployed as separate independent microservices but often these two microservices need to talk to each other. A HRM user creates a company contact employee and the HRM microservice API saves the information related to HRM inside HRM module in 'hrm' database while the employee details like name, surname, address etc will be saved to CRM database calling the CRM microservice APIs i.e. the Contact API saves the above info as contact of type 'Internal' or 'Employee'.
So basically what I am trying to do here is separating the data related to each microservices.

**Is this way of domain design correct?** or should I have to process and store all the information (entered by a HRM permissioned user) inside HRM module and 'hrm' database? such that we don't care CRM. And if so, CRM only seems to manage EXTERNAL contacts only? Will this have any future problems?

Comment: Can you please explain how your question relates to domain-driven design (DDD) ?

Comment: In this context, the CRM and HRM are not huge applications that we see everyday. 
I have few services to operate on accounts, contacts and leads in the CRM.
Similarly, few services related to HRM functionality and one, like adding employees.
So DDD problem for me is, while adding an employee by a HRM user: Should I keep the HRM related information in HRM, and employee name, address etc in the contacts of the CRM? OR HRM needs to handle everything regarding adding an employee.

Comment: But I can't see any terms related to a domain driven design approach here (domains, subdomains, bounded contexts, aggregates, etc.) I'm just asking because I'm afraid you misused the ddd tag on your question and people might answer beside the point.

Comment: Ok, so in terms of DDD as I understand, here is a full contact domain in CRM i.e. 'Contact' having id, name, lastName, address. The bounded context is Addition/Modification/Removal of Contact. The Aggregate is ContactService responsible for adding, changing, removing contacts. Similarly, an Employee having name, lastName, address etc in HRM is a full employee domain. The bounded context is within the operations addition/modification/removal of employee. The Aggregate is the EmployeeService responsible for adding, changing, removing employees.

Comment: My question is: Do we need to consider employee as a contact? Are these 2 things related in practice? if so, do we have a shared bounded context? such that ContactService is a sub-set of operations of EmployeeService.

Is there any business benefit of separating the contact table and employee table in practice? 
What is the recommended practice such that whatever new features coming will be adjusted by the initial design?

Comment: It's not that there is a business benefit to separating the contact table and employee table, it's that **why on earth would you put them together in the first place ?**

Comment: Because in the requirement in the CRM module, there is a contact model already that has name, lastname, address etc. The employee model (in HRM module) has all the fields of contact model with added two or three new properties like jobStartDate, position. 

So the things like even why duplicate model which leads to redundant codes instead, reuse of codes, reuse of table namespace etc came to my mind, and I am trying to make things as cleaner as possible. I feel that I am lagging some important thing, please suggest me where I am breaking while trying to build this whole concept.

Comment: Thanks guillaume31. I got the answers to solve my real problem from your last answer in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your question really relates to DDD and how much you want to embrace DDD, but it has this important notion of ubiquitous language. That language contains very precise and unambiguous domain terms which must be the same in the domain expert's mouth, in all the models and ultimately in the code.

A Contact is a Contact. An Employee is an Employee. They have different names for a reason. They reflect different domain concepts.

Unless a Contact can somehow turn out to also be an Employee (which only an expert in your domain can tell and certainly not someone on StackOverflow), *there's no reason for them to share anything* - whether it be a database table, a base class, etc., and even less so if they are in different Bounded Contexts.

Comment: So many thanks, I got more light to solve my problem from the last paragraph you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things here:

1) CRM and HRM are *not* microservices.  There is nothing micro about these domains.

2) In general, you want as little coupling between services as possible.  That doesn't mean you can't use compositional patterns, but you should think about why you are using them in any given situation.  If you are doing it just to avoid code-duplication or database duplication, you should really think skeptically about it.

What do you want to accomplish by putting the employees into the CRM database? Is it just that you already have a "person" domain/database in CRM?  If so, your case for keeping employees in your CRM is very weak.  If, on the other hand, your goal is to treat employees as customers, and internally market to them, then putting employees in the CRM is probably valuable.

I would really suggest you look at designing these as separate stores.  It will allow these systems to evolve independently, scale independently, etc.

If you really want all contacts in a single system, consider a new service (maybe something more "micro"), that stores and retrieves contacts.  This could be used by both services, but will be independent of each.

Comment: Vote for "CRM and HRM are not microservices", they are neither "micro" nor "bounded context".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The context I described of CRM and HRM was fictional, just to illustrate the point. I should have asked like 'how to communicate in between the several micro services with data consistency'.